# Win 10 Creators Update 1703: how to reactivate free icon placement?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-icons, windows-10-v1703

Since for ever I put my icons at the bottom of the screen, so far the descriptions aren't even visible. My taskbar is at the top.

But since the update there is huge usable zone for icons at the bottom and left side, at least 2 cm where I cant place anything, on the other edges I don't get as close to the screen border as I'm used to too.

Right after the update all looks fine but if I touch an icon and move it they all jump away from the screens edge towards the middle and wont move back.

Updated on another PC, same thing, just not as bad, the "no icon zone" is much more smaller there, just a few pixels. But thats still useless because I cant move out the description text anymore.

Will this get fixed? How can I get back the control over my icons?

Comment: If you make a new user, does the 'zone' exist for them as well?  Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Yes a new user has the same restrictions. Also messing around with the vertical and horizontal spacing doesn't help much, it moves the unusable areas, but not good enough.

What do you expect to see on a screenshot? Its just icons that are not near the desktop border. When before the update I was able to put them directly at the screens edge and even move them beyond if I wanted.

Comment: "What do you expect to see on a screenshot?"  Seeing how much of a gap (and how they're laying themselves out) may give a clue as to what's going on.  Are the two PCs you updated similar in hardware?  If you boot Windows into [Safe Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode), does it behave the same way?

Comment: The main difference that matters is I guess the resolution. The one with the largest gap that I can't close is a 4K screen, the one where its sort of mangable is just 2560x1600 both run with a 125% scaling. But messing around with the scaling doesn't help much either, and its required to stay in that area anyway. But the fact remains that MS introduced borders for your icons that correspond with your screens borders if your luck and really messes up you design if it doesn't line up. They probably thought it would be a good idea not to move icons half way out of the screen anymore.